# How does Diablo 3 local multiplayer work?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I know that I can play solo but if I want to play with friends over at my place, do they need to bring a USB stick with their character over? Can I make them a separate character on my account?

Answer (score 1):

They can make a separate character on your account, or bring their own and put it on another PS3 account without problem.

Source: My own experience in local multiplayer ("split-screen") of D3.

Comment: Alright, but if they brought their own character on a USB stick would I need PS+? One time I tried to load a Battlefield 3 save file on a USB stick and it wouldn't let me saying I needed PS+.

Comment: If this happen, try to create a new PS3 account (on XMB, all left), and try to charge the save on the new account. You should not need PS+

Comment: You mean same screen multiplayer